# How to atomically modify a value within a mutable array?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, massiv

I have this mutable array in an `ST` monad. And I have this loop function.

```
 runST $ do
    myarray <- newMArray (Sz 10) 0
    loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) (\j ->
      loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) (\i ->
        when (mytruthcheck j i)
             (modifyM_ myarray (pure . (+1)) ((funcofji j i) :: Int)
     )))
```

I want to use `forkST_` to run the outer loop in parallel like this.

```
runST $ do
   myarray <- newMArray (Sz 10) 0
   loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) (\j ->
     void (forkST_ (loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) (\i ->
       when (mytruthcheck j i)
            (Data.Massiv.Array.Mutable.modifyM_
                 myarray (pure . (+1)) ((funcofji j i) :: Int)
    ))))
```

But I’m guessing this will cause thread collisions but I don’t really know although I do know it is possible that `funcofji` can output the same value for different values of `j` and therefore the loop can modify the same index of `myarray` for different `j` s. Is there a way to ensure this is done atomically or is that already the case?

Btw here’s the `loopM_` function

```
loopM_ :: Monad m => Int -> (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> m a) -> m ()
loopM_ !init' condition increment f = go init'
  where
    go !step
      | condition step = f step >> go (increment step)
      | otherwise = pure ()
```

Comment: Pretty sure if you were to enforce atomicity then the cache penalty would destroy any multithreading advantage there is to be had. It could only pay off if you're computing a really expensive function on each array element.

Comment: I’m using an inexpensive operation on each array element. But maybe it’s worth trying? The loop size of j is close to 100,000 and the loop size of i is close to 1 Billion. It’s worth mentioning also that the function does complete its execution albeit after several hours which is fine for my uses but I would like to optimize it further if possible.

Comment: If array size is not too big then you can compute parallel part with different arrays and then merge them together (there is a monoid).

Comment: If you want parallelizm (not concurency) then the count of Haskell threads produced by`forkST`/`forkIO` should be releveant to the count of the CPUs/Cores on the your machine. Otherwise will be overhead.

Comment: @freestyle assuming I switched to IO instead of using ST. Should I use forkOn instead of forkIO since I have set my RTS -N option?

Comment: @Anon No. There is not problem with `forkST`, there is a problem with how many you call `forkST`. `forkOn` cant help you. You should to split you range of iterations on the some count (which can be equal to the count of the CPUs are on you machine) and then fork the loop on the subrange.

Comment: Another problem with your implementation is that you don't wait for all the parallel work to complete.

Comment: Making accesses atomic isn't good enough. You need to make them both atomic *and commutative* to retain ST's guarantee of determinism.

Comment: @DanielWagner since I’m doing addition on these elements commutativity is satisfied right?

Comment: I think so, yes. I couldn't read the `massiv` code well enough to be sure what you were doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments, atomic modification is only useful for concurrency <strike>which doesn't look like what is needed here. What you need is parallelism.</strike>, which is available in massiv for `Int`s: [`atomicAddIntArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array-Mutable-Atomic.html#v:atomicAndIntArray)

There is also a builtin way to do parallelism in `massiv` very efficiently, so there is definitely no need to reinvent the wheel:

```hs
  createArray_ Par (Sz 10) $ \scheduler myarray ->
    loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) $ \j ->
      loopM_ 0 (<10) (+1) $ \i ->
        when (mytruthcheck j i) $ 
          scheduleWork_ scheduler $ 
            void $ atomicAddIntArray myarray ((funcofji j i) :: Int) 1
```

Also don't lie to yourself, ST (state thread) was not build for multi-threading, use IO instead. However, if you can guarantee, that despite multi-threaded setup, the outcome that is produced is still deterministic in the end, then it is ok to use `unsafePerformIO`.

**Edit**

I just noticed this comment:

> The loop size of j is close to 100,000 and the loop size of i is close to 1 Billion.

Which makes me believe that it will be better to parallelize it in this way instead:

```hs
  createArray_ Par (Sz 10) $ \scheduler myarray ->
    iforSchedulerM_ scheduler (0 ..: (100000 :. 1000000000)) $ \_ (j :. i) ->
      when (mytruthcheck j i) $ 
        void $ atomicAddIntArray myarray ((funcofji j i) :: Int) 1
```

This will ensure that you only schedule a few jobs, instead of billions. Check out [`iforSchedulerM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:iforSchedulerM_) implementation in order to customize it parallelization if you have more insight into your per `i` and `j` workload.

Comment: I think that will not work correctly, because `modifyM_` is not atomic. It is a problem which @Anon try to solve. That solution might be correct if `funcofji` returns distinct indexes.

Comment: I see,then using atomic increment will work just fine.  I made an edit, however before arguing performance I'd recommend benchmarking it, I am more then sure it will be fine.

Comment: I agree with you. Better to write a benchmark first and then try to improve performance from a simple solution to a complex one.

Comment: @lehins the cpu core utilization is often approaching 100% across all cores fluctuating between that and 70%. So that’s a good sign. The only negative is that it uses 3x as much memory. This isn’t really a problem right now but it can be depending on several things. I’ll try changing the RTS memory settings to see if I can keep the cpu performance while using less memory.

Comment: @Anon I added another solution, that should work better for your workload, I think.

Comment: @lehins the new solution has even more consistent near 100% cpu utilization and also uses about 80% more memory than my original solution instead of 3x. Although the memory usage reduction was noticed after I had already changed the RTS memory settings, and I haven’t checked it yet with the setting I had before. So the memory usage reduction could be due that as well. Anyway thank you and I’ll comment the time to completion factor compared to my original solution when it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of the discussion in the comments, I wrote a prototype of how this could be, maybe it will be useful (I didn't try to compile so there are maybe some type/syntax errors).

```
runST $ do
    let arrsz = 10 :: Int -- depends on codomain of funcofji
    let ncaps = 8 :: Int64 -- see also getNumCapabilities
    let outerLoopSize = 10^5  :: Int64
    let innerLoopSize = 10^12 :: Int64
    let chunksz = ceiling $ fromIntegral outerLoopSize / fromIntegral ncaps
    
    sync <- newEmptyMVar
    forM_ [0 .. ncaps - 1] $ \k -> forkST_ $ do
        localArr <- newMArray (Sz arrsz) 0
        forM_ [k * chunksz .. min outerLoopSize ((k + 1) * chunksz) - 1] $ \j -> do
            forM_ [0 .. innerLoopSize - 1] $ \i -> do
                when (mytruthcheck j i) $
                    modifyM_ localArr (pure . (+1)) $ funcofji j i
        putMVar sync localArr

    resultArr <- takeMVar sync
    replicateM_ (ncaps - 1) $ do
        localArr <- takeMVar sync
        forM_ [0 .. arrsz - 1] $ do \ix ->
            elm <- readM localArr ix
            modifyM_ resultArr (pure . (+elm)) ix

    ...
```

Comment: @freestyles I noticed that `formM_ [0 .. ncaps -1]` should be  `[0 .. ncaps]` instead so that the remainder of `outerLoopSize` will run after the end of the last `chunksz`

Comment: @Anon Yes, you are right, my mistake. I fixed remainder problem by add them to chunks. It is possible because as I understand the order of iterations is not matter.

Comment: another way might be to divide by `(ncaps -1)`  instead and then go from `[0..naps-1]` so you still have  8 threads in the list but 7 equal sized chunks with one 1 remainder chunk

Comment: @Anon Yes, but `ncaps` can be `1` and `nremainders` can be `0`. So maybe need something like: `let chunksz = let (sz, nrems) = divMod outerLoopSize ncaps in if 0 == nrems then sz else div outerLoopSize (ncaps - 1)`.

Comment: @Anon or like this: `let chunksz = ceiling $ fromIntegral outerLoopSize / fromIntegral ncaps`